# Anaconda Navigator or Conda is not found post installation

Tags: anaconda

I installed Anaconda Package on Windows 10. The installation is completed but i cannot find anaconda navigator in the start menu. Also i tried to find conda info in the command prompt but could not find it. My installation directory shows some packages but when i try to open any exe it does not work.
Can someone please help?

I tried changing all permutations of two check box that appear at the start of the installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install OS Bit specific version. I was installing 32bit Package on 64Bit OS